# Nuxt3: how to configure eslint?

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint, nuxtjs3

Nuxt3: how to configure eslint

```sh
npx nuxi init nuxt3-app
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a how-to website. [This page](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/792) is the latest and most up to date link talking about this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using typescript,
you can add [`@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript) as dev dependency

And create `.eslintrc` with

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "off"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

If you do not use typescript,
add [`@nuxtjs/eslint-config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/eslint-config) insead of `@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript`

And create `.eslintrc` with

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "@nuxtjs"
  ],
}
```

---

More details about nuxt linter available here: https://github.com/nuxt/eslint-config

Comment: That one is not Nuxt3 specific AFAIK. Not like it matters a lot anyway I have to say.

Answer (score 0):

Installs the following libraries.

```
- @nuxtjs/eslint-config
- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
- @typescript-eslint/parser    
- eslint
- eslint-config-standard
- eslint-config-standard-with-typescript
- eslint-plugin-import
- eslint-plugin-n
- eslint-plugin-promise
- eslint-plugin-vue
```

some of them are installed by default by eslint.

then in your `.eslintrc.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
    'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/base',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'standard'
  ],
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'vue',
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
}
```